# Generators of the group of invertible elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$—are they multiplicative or additive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When I was asked to find the generators of the group of invertible elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$, which are denoted as $\phi(14)$, I did not realize whether the generators are multiplicative or additive. Which is it?

If both are equally valid, then why did the author omit mention of the type of generators?

Comment: I doubt that the notation $\phi(14)$ is used for that. The Euler (totient) function $\phi(n)$ denotes the number of elements of the group of invertible elements of the ring $\Bbb{Z}_n$. Those elements are also exactly the generators of the additive group $\Bbb{Z}_n$, but the question is different. The notation $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$ does mean the group of invertible elements. Some authors use $\Bbb{Z}_n^\times$, yet other authors use $U(n)$. Various dangers of notation overload lie ahead.

Comment: This is just a matter of knowing the definition. An element $x$ of a ring is called invertible if there exists $y$ in the ring with $xy=yx=1$. The invertible elements never form a group under addition (except for the trivial ring consisting of $0$ alone), so the operation has to be multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any ring $R$, it is standard to consider the set of units
$$R^\times=\{a\in R:\textsf{there exists some }\,b\in R\,\textsf{ with }\,a\cdot b=b\cdot a=1\}$$
as a group under the multiplication operation of $R$. ([Here's the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)#Group_of_units).)

(*In fact, if $R$ is not the trivial ring, then $R^\times$ is not* ***closed*** *under the addition operation of $R$, so it certainly will not be a group under that operation.*)

You're told to look at the group of units of $R=\mathbb{Z}_{14}$, namely the set 
$$(\mathbb{Z}_{14})^\times=\{\overline{1},\overline{3},\overline{5},\overline{9},\overline{11},\overline{13}\}$$
under the multiplication operation of $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$, and you are looking for the elements $x\in(\mathbb{Z}_{14})^\times$ that generate the entire group, i.e., the elements with the property that
$$(\mathbb{Z}_{14})^\times=\{x^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
([Here's the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n).)

Comment: Here's my thinking on this: If Z_4 is the ring, then {1,2,3} is not a group because 2*2 is 0, which is not in the group. So closure is not satisfied.

Comment: @David: You're right, $\{\overline{1},\overline{2},\overline{3}\}$ is not a group under the multiplication operation of $\mathbb{Z}_4$, for the reason you observed. However, $\overline{2}$ is **not a unit of the ring** $\mathbb{Z}_4$, so your observation is not relevant. In fact, the unit group is
$$(\mathbb{Z}_4)^\times=\{\overline{1},\overline{3}\}$$
which you can easily check ***is*** closed under the multiplication operation of $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: I do not understand the notation Z/nZ and how it is different from the notation Z_n. I am using the latter and you the former. Could you please explain the difference to me?

Comment: There is no difference, they are exactly synonymous. ([Take a look at this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n).) I've changed my responses to match your choice however, to avoid any unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I meant that I knew they have been used synonymously before (and that you were), but I want to know what the difference is. I read somewhere that the notation Z/nZ is more faithful or accurate or something like that. Why is that?

Comment: Firstly, it follows a more general notation for taking a ring $R$ and a particularly nice subset $I\subset R$ called an ideal, and forming the quotient ring $R/I$ ([here's the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)). Secondly, the notation $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ already has a different meaning, namely, the $n$-adic integers ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Algebraic_approach)). The notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is therefore usually only seen in introductory courses attempting to use simple notation.

Comment: However, do you understand my point about $\{\overline{1},\overline{2},\overline{3}\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Invertible elements of a ring form a group *under multiplication*, but never under addition (e.g., 0 does not belong to that set).

So this should be clear.